# Change the form fields according to the type of registration user choose

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

My idea is the following: on my website, the user will be able to register a product or customer. However, the components on the form to register one of these two are obviously different. I would like to place a dropdown menu for the user to choose which registration they want to make, customer or product, and based on their choice, the fields presented would be different. How to do this using react-hook-form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

function RegistrationForm() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
  const selectedOption = watch('registrationType'); // Watch the dropdown value

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    // Handle form submission based on the selected option (customer or product)
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <label>Choose Registration Type:</label>
        <Controller
          name="registrationType"
          control={control}
          defaultValue="" // Set a default value
          render={({ field }) => (
            <select {...field}>
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              <option value="customer">Customer</option>
              <option value="product">Product</option>
            </select>
          )}
        />
      </div>

      {selectedOption === 'customer' && (
        <div>
          {/* Customer-specific fields */}
          <label>Customer Name:</label>
          <input {...register('customerName')} />
          {/* Add more customer-specific fields here */}
        </div>
      )}

      {selectedOption === 'product' && (
        <div>
          {/* Product-specific fields */}
          <label>Product Name:</label>
          <input {...register('productName')} />
          {/* Add more product-specific fields here */}
        </div>
      )}

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!